# AWS SSH Login continues to fail even with new EC2 instance [Permission denied (PublicKey)]

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I just started working with AWS to create a wordpress site on an EC2 instance (using the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WR7EFFLF04). Everything was working fine until I tried to add an SSL certificate using another tutorial (I can't seem to find right now).

In following those steps, something broke the site (assumed DNS error) to where it wouldn't load because of too many redirects. When I went back through the tutorial to try to fix what I had done, I got to where it had me log in via SSH which I had previously done without any issues and I began getting a "Permission denied (PublicKey)" error.

Since then, I haven't been able to login to that instance or any other instances without getting the same error. I've even tried creating a new instance with a brand new key and I still get that same error.

When I run the command with verbose on, it gives me this output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-13-59-207-225.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/bradley/Desktop/John and Rhonda Wordpress Files/keypair-2.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bradley/Desktop/John and Rhonda Wordpress Files/keypair-2.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-13-59-207-225.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:OiIQ5QiVxQvN9lAkjLm90ynddjDDs9L75PqDAL/cTv4
debug1: Host 'ec2-13-59-207-225.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/bradley/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/bradley/Desktop/John and Rhonda Wordpress Files/keypair-2.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bradley/Desktop/John and Rhonda Wordpress Files/keypair-2.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
admin@ec2-13-59-207-225.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publicly).
```

Any idea what could be going on?

*I originally had this question over on stack overflow that got shutdown for being off-topic so if this isn't the right place for this question, please let me know where is :)*